# spot the error (short locate function) - C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 2D array represented by a 1D array, and my task is to locate the first instance of the colour in the array, store the x and y coordinates in *x and *y and return 0. If not, then return 1.

There are no errors, but the server test for my class is showing all tests failing for this function. Can anyone spot any error or mistake?
Thanks

```
int locate_color(  const uint8_t array[], 
       unsigned int cols, 
       unsigned int rows,
       uint8_t color,
       unsigned int *x,
       unsigned int *y )
{
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<cols;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<rows;j++)
    {    
        if(array[i+(j*cols)]==color)
        {
            *y=i;
            *x=j;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: What are the test inputs and expected outputs. We need more information ...

Comment: colors are (usually) defined by a red(8bits),blue(8bits),green(8bits) and optionally a transparency(8bits) sequence that is normally fit into a 32 bit value. (or in a pixel map into a 3 byte or 4 byte sequence for each pixel.)

Comment: to start: an array is stored in memory by row: and within the row by column.   Therefore, the outer loop should be the row number and the inner loop the column number.   Didn't they tell you in class how an array is placed into memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the passed argument values with reversed row and column.

```
*y=i;
*x=j;
```

should be

```
*y=j;
*x=i;
```

Comment: Hard to spot, indeed. Wouldn't have happened with proper variable names like `row` and `col`.